# Laravel5.3 Elixir でのgulp watchが動かない

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-5

Laravel 5.3 でwebアプリケーションを作成しています。

Elixirにてgulpを行っているのですが、gulp watchで毎回

```
stream.js:74
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
  ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat path/to/versioningfile
at Error (native)
```

このようなエラーを吐きます。(`stat`の部分が`chmod`のときもアリ)

`gulpfile.js`はdocument通りに、このように書いています。

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');


elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass(['app.scss', 'another.scss'])
       .webpack('app.js')
       .copy('resources/assets/img', 'public/img');
});


elixir(mix => {
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

解決策をご存知の方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/626#issuecomment-248315193 に elixir の呼び出しで一度に一つの事だけやるようにすると、とりあえず動くよ、的な報告があります。

Comment: @mjy さん コメントありがとうございます！  `elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass(['./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css', 'app.scss'])
       .webpack('app.js')
       .copy('resources/assets/img', 'public/img')
       .version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});`
以上のように修正してみましたが、挙動は特に変わらず..といった感じです(. .)

Comment: たぶん、そういう事では無くて、一つを残して他はコメントアウトする、という事だと思います。`sass`の編集中は`sass`の記述だけ残し、JavaScriptの編集中は`webpack`だけ残す、というような作業をしているのかと。やってられないですが、原因究明の足掛りにはなりそうです。（なお、追加の情報がある場合は、コメントではなく質問の編集を行なうとよいです。他の方の目にもとまりますから）

Comment: @mjyさん なるほどです..！またここの使い方に関してもありがとうございます。